# How to pass color props by Nivo ResponsiveBar?

Tags: reactjs, nivo-react

I use Nivo's responsive bar.
I want to show a bar like the image. And I can do it if I set the colors directly like below . But I can set it by passing the props or set by a function.
How can I do it?

```
<ResponsiveBar
  colors='#0481F8'
/>
```

[image]

- By a function

```
const getColor = () => title===A ? '#0481F8' : title===B ? '#F98700'

<ResponsiveBar
  title={title}
  data={data}
  colors={getColor()}
/>
```

- By passing props

**Parent**

```
<Chart color='#0481F8' data=...>
```

**Child**

```
const Chart = ({data, color}) => {

return (
<>
<ResponsiveBar
  data={data}
  colors={color}
/>
</>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set it through props, `ResponsiveBar` can take multiple `colors` also. You should use it as,

```
<Chart color={['#0481F8']} data={..}>

const Chart = ({data, color}) => {

return (
<ResponsiveBar
  data={data}
  colors={color}
/>
)}
```

Comment: Well... Even though I passed string[], it didn't work.

Comment: It has some recent changes perhaps `   colors={{ scheme: 'nivo' }}` see dedicated documentation for coolers here there are pre defined scheme you will have to use one from the list - https://nivo.rocks/guides/colors

Comment: Thanks. I read it. But there's no clue...

Comment: which library are you using `@nivo/bar` ? or old one ? It should be `import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar';` from - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nivo/bar. I have tested color works perfectly fine if passed parameter as  ` colors={['#0481F8']}` and using in `<ResponsiveBar .... colors={colors}`

Comment: I use `"@nivo/bar": "^0.79.1",`.  Also I use like  `import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar'`. Hmm...

Comment: It didn't work by passing props. But another way which is by a function, I could do it. When I didn't make it as a function but as a variable.